# 'for' loop won't loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, mathematical-optimization

I have the following code

```
for i = 1:8760
    A = [PVtech(i,:) WTtech(i,:)];
    b = demand(i);
    f = [CRF * PVtechcost(i,:) .* PVcap(i,:) ./ PVtech(i,:) CRF*WTtechcost(i,:) .* WTcap(i,:) ./ WTtech(i,:)];
    x(i) = linprog(f, A,b,[], [], lb);
end
```

I'm trying to optimize `linprog` over the 8760 data set but can't seem to get the loop going for each row.
When I run it I get a size of `A to be 1x30 (when it should be 8760 by 30).

Does anyone see where I have coded wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every time you run it you are overwriting A with the single row [PVtech(i,:) WTtech(i,:)]

Try this: `A = [A; PVtech(i,:) WTtech(i,:)];` i.e. vertical concatenation

With preallocation your code would look like this:

```
numRows = 8760;
A = zeros(numRows, 30);

for i = 1:numRows

    A(i,:) = [PVtech(i,:) WTtech(i,:)];

    b = demand(i);

    f = [CRF*PVtechcost(i,:).*PVcap(i,:)./PVtech(i,:) CRF*WTtechcost(i,:).*WTcap(i,:)./WTtech(i,:)];

    x(i) = linprog(f, A,b,[], [], lb);

end
```

Comment: Thanks Dan but that gives me an undefined variable error for A

Comment: try pre-allocating before the loop: `A = zeros(8760,30)`, and use `A(i,:) = [PVtech(i,:) WTtech(i,:)]`

Comment: Yes, you must declare A first so you can try A = [] but it is faster as @Amro has pointed out to preallocate so maybe A = zeros(8760,30)

Comment: I have followed your suggestions and what I get is only the first row of A filled with the correct values. All the other rows are zeros

Comment: Set a breakpoint and use the debugger. You need to learn MATLAB, not have others write your code for you.

Comment: I am confused as to why I need to debug this and why it shouldn't work in the first place?What sort of errors can the debugger come up with?

Comment: @user643469: The debugger is an extremely powerful tool for development with Matlab. It allows you to inspect the values of all the variables, and to evaluate and improve the problematic line in the command window until you get it right. As to the error, I have fixed it in Dan's post.

Comment: Why does `linprog` needs the full matrix `A` at each iteration and not only `A(i,:)`?